# The "xs" grid option at bootstrap 3 has too much range to fit a web page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The col-xs-* is used to control screen with with range: 0-767px.
This appears to be too large for my site.
In my case, I need grid options for **a screen width that is larger than 500px** AND another **with range less than 500px**, and that enables me to manage iphone screen with 320px for example.
I already has the media query as an answer, but I am expecting a more elegant  answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only solution is to manually change your bootstrap media query dimensions..

Answer (score 1):

Customize and Download your own version of Bootstrap after modifying the media query breakpoints:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints.

Alternatively, if you have `node` and `grunt` available on your system, you can actually add more `LESS` variables, such as a `col-xss-*`, or `col-xlg-*`, but this would require you to modify the source code (which is available to download VIA bootstrap's website).

Long story short, there isn't a way short of modifying the underlying bootstrap code.

Comment: How to use that? Say the @screen-xs which covers 480px ?

Comment: +1 for the less suggestion, Most of the less customization to col-xs was deprecated as of v3.0.1. But adding your own less variables is not hard with a little googling, you can always edit the core bootstrap.css if you save it to a local copy.